# The bonus question in calc class.

Tags: calculus

The bonus question:

> Let $f(x)$ be defined for $a \leq x \leq b$. Assuming appropriate properties of continuity and derivability, prove for $a < x < b$ that
>   $$ \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}{x-b} = \tfrac{1}{2}f^{\prime \prime}(\beta) $$
>   where $\beta$ is some number between $a$ and $b$.

I am thinking that its just the Mean Value Theorem.

$$f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

I have rewritten the problem as this:

$$\frac{f^{\prime}(c)-f^{\prime}(d)}{c-d}$$  for $c$ and $d$ within $(a,b)$.

Then I get lost, I don't see where the contant $1/2$ comes into play and how to have the denomiator be $x-b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting these pieces together should give you the result

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(\beta)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}, g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{x-a}- \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}$$

$$  \frac{g(x) - g(b)}{x-b}=g'(c)$$

Edit: The first formula is from the Taylor expansion of $f$
You can also derive it using twice rolle on
$$ h(t)= f(t)-f(a)-f'(a)(t-a)- \frac{(t-a)^2}{(x-a)^2}(f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a))$$
first rolle $h(a)=h(x)=0 \Rightarrow h'(x_1)=0 x_1\in (a,x)$

second rolle on $h'(a)=h'(x_1)=0 \Rightarrow h''(\beta)=0 \beta \in (0,x_1)$

And $h''(\beta)=0$ is what you want

Comment: isn't that taylor series expansion?